# How can I make a email sent via PHP follow the past sent emails?

Tags: php, email

I have an web page where users can send a feedback via an email sent with PHP. When that feedback is sent the user gets an email confirming that their message was relayed. Inside that email will be the feedback message of the user. What I am trying to figure out is how can I respond to their feedback so that the email I send to the user attaches itself with the first email sent?

Basically how can I attach emails together for the user mailbox?

Comment: do you respond via a web-form or a email client ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "send to the user attaches itself with the first email sent?"?

Comment: You know in GMail when you email someone and they respond and then you email them again...Etc... You see the "discussion" all in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email threads are created by setting the `Message-ID` header in he original message and then referencing that message-id in the  `References` / `In-Reply-To` headers in all follow-up messages. See [RFC2822 Section 3.6.4 - "Identification fields"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4) .

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending your emails via the built in php [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) method you can specify additional headers in the fourth option.

```
<?php
  mail( $to, $subject, $message, 'Reply-to: '. $replyAddress ."\r\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use **PHPMailer**